# Do nuclear particles react to heat?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I would like to ask if the nuclear and sub nuclear particles react to heat energy supplied to them. For example the quark triads in protons and neutrons?

Comment: How do you define "temperature" in this case?

Comment: Same question... what is "heat" energy supposed to be in this case? The closest you can come to a thermodynamic scenario is a quark-gluon plasma. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: no i am asking about the scenerio in which neutrons and protons are fused due to great heat and pressure. I would like to know the situation of the quarks present inside them.

Comment: It's similar to what happens to nuclei during chemical reactions, they are mostly unaffected. Fusion doesn't change the number of neutrons and protons.

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114120/44126

Answer (score 1):

Thermal energy affects condensed matter, molecules, atoms, and nuclei by exciting atomic transitions with energies of roughly $E=kT$ and below.  At room temperature $T=300\,\rm K$, $kT = 25\,\rm meV$ you mostly excite vibrational states in solids, whence the expression "heat is jiggling atoms."  At room temperature you can generally make molecules rotate, but not vibrate.  I don't have vibrational energies at hand, but you start to make electronic excitations in atoms when you get $kT \approx 1\,\rm eV$, corresponding to $T\approx 12\,000\,\rm K$.  Since molecules are held together by electronic interactions, this is the sort of temperature where you can reliably dissociate molecules and you expect to find *most* atoms *not* in the ground state.

Generally the first excited state in a nucleus is a couple of MeV above the ground state.  So from the perspective of a nucleus any temperature below hundreds of millions of kelvin is "absolute zero," in the sense that you are astoundingly unlikely to have a thermal excitation drive the nucleus away from the ground state.  Ordinary temperatures do *not* have enough energy to thermally excite nuclei.

With quarks bound into nucleons the situation is more extreme.  The "first excited state" of the nucleon is the $\Delta$ baryon with mass around 1200 MeV.  You won't find thermally-produced $\Delta$s until $kT$ approaches 200 MeV.

Ordinarily you can't talk about temperature unless you are pretty close to a thermal equilibrium; by definition, almost, all the nuclear reactions we observe are far from equilibrium.
However, "temperature" turns out to be a pretty good way to describe the energy density in a strongly interacting fluid like the quark-gluon plasma, which was the state of matter for the first minute or so after the Big Bang.