# Term for maximum temperature value

Tags: temperature, terminology

Objects falling in the earth's atmosphere can reach a terminal velocity in which they can fall no faster. Is there a synonymous term for objects heating up?

Comment: What's wrong with "maximum temperature"? Or do you think there should be a free-fall specific maximum temperature vocabulary?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape - "maximum temperature" sounds good to me. In my question, I was attempting to seek a term that relates to a known value such as 5 Billion degrees, if one exists. Thanks for your comment. I understand this is a basic question.

Comment: Steady state temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “Planck temperature” is

$$
T_\text{P} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c^5}{G k_\text{B}^2}}
\approx 1.42\times 10^{32}\rm\,K
$$

Some sources refer to this as a “maximum temperature,” by the same logic under which the “Planck length” $\ell_P = \sqrt{\hbar G/c^3}$ is a “minimum length.” But it’s probably more accurate to say that, as the temperature approaches this threshold, there will be quantum-gravity things happening that we currently don’t have any model for. The Wikipedia page currently says

> An object with the temperature of ($T_P$) would emit a black body radiation with a peak wavelength of $\ell_P$, where each photon and each individual collision would have the energy to create a micro black hole of Planck mass. There are no known physical models able to describe temperatures greater than or equal to $T_P$.

To my reading the Wikipedia prediction is overconfident; I think there is lots of room for new physics at lower temperatures.

You might like this [old post about high-temperature plasmas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114120/44126).